# After copying xib and ViewController to a new project my app doesn't draw and crashes on touch events

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have copied some files from a very small (and working) project to a bigger Xcode project.
In particular I have copied a xib file (with just one UIView subclass element), the UIView subclass, and ViewController.
The smaller project simply draws a color background and draws circles as long as the user touches the screen.

I have adapted the code of the bigger project so that at the beginning it loads the xib file. I have added this to the AppDelegate so that it loads the new xib instead of the old one.
(see edit #1 for more details)

Even if drawRect is called (I've tested adding NSLog) nothing is shown[*]. Moreover if I click on the screen of the simulated iPhone the app crashes.

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I am not sure where the problem lies so please let me what I can post.
I have Xcode 4 and I am working with iOS 5.

Thanks for your help. I hope this question is not too naive.

**EDIT #1**:
This is my xib with a list of classes. I am trying to edit the source code for a [Jabber Client that I have found here](https://github.com/funkyboy/Building-a-Jabber-client-for-iOS) inserting my own views.
I cannot post image but this is the link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDsNb.png

The class CircleDrawer is handling touches and drawing circles.
The class MTViewController is sending a test message.
The class JabberClientAppDelegate (basically unchanged from the downloaded code), connects to the server and authenticates the user. What I have changed is this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[MTViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MTViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;

/*
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;*/
```

}

EDIT #2:
I am starting from scratch.
I am trying to rebuild the app but I get a crash. I have started another discussion since it is not directly relevant to this problem.
[EXC_BAD_ACCESS right after touchesBegan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218541/exc-bad-access-right-after-touchesbegan)

[*]: if I simulate pressing the home button for an instant I can see the background color (then of course I don't see anything else because the simulator returns to the springboard).

Comment: I suspect you haven't connected things up in Interface Builder.

Comment: That's what I am afraid of too... could you maybe tell me how to do it? I have been looking for tutorials on this but they all refer to the "App Delegate" object in Interface Builder... which I don't have (I only have file's owner, first responder, and my custom UIView)

Comment: Well it means you need to connect the outlets from the view controller to the view items in IB and connect the delegate back to the view controllers/app delegates, as appropriate.  I cannot tell you more than that, without seeing the Xib and class definitions.

Comment: Update: you have no app delegate?  You'll have to add it manually then.

Comment: Do you know why there is no app delegate? In any case I have updated the questions with more info, please let me know if you need more.

Comment: You can create the App Delegate by dragging a (plain) Object from the Library in IB and then changing it's class to the app delegate class (the project template should have created the class for you, at least).  Then connect the delegate of each view controller back to the app delegate.  You might need a window too, in which case follow this tutorial: http://www.trappers.tk/site/2011/06/16/mainwindow-xib

Comment: I've followed the tutorial you have posted but I have two doubts. (1) Why should I connect the file's owner delegate to my app delegate? (2) why is there no "delegate" in my file's owner's outlets? (see http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/155/screenshot20111121at152.png ). I apologize if I am asking naive questions.

Comment: Doesn't the `delegate` appear in the connections tab (the 2nd one)?

Comment: This is what the connection inspector shows (is this what you are asking, right?) http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/208/screenshot20111121at153.png/

Comment: (btw, I've just tried to create a new "single view app" project and there is no app delegate in the xib nor delegate outlet in file's owner)

Comment: Xcode 4.2 creates objects manually now, where as they used to reside in the nib file.  It's a pain when you are following an oldish tutorial.

Comment: Do you know how I might add the delegate outlet -if this is the path I should take-? Thank you

Comment: The reason why "delegate" does not appear in file's owner is that file's owner class is MTViewController and not UIApplication. I am bit confused about whether this is correct or not. What do you think?

Comment: This conversation is getting out of hand now :)  The class won't have a delegate, but the view (the bit in IB) will.

Comment: Sorry... Is it correct that File's Owner is of MTViewController class? Is it correct that MTViewController is a subclass of UIViewController? And, finally, is it correct that "delegate" does not appear in the outlets?

Comment: The first questions seem correct, however, for the third, are you looking at the "Connections" with the view selected within IB?

Comment: Yes -and thanks for your patience.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not at my Mac at the moment, so I cannot check :)  Looking at the docs, however, it seems not every UIViewController will have a delegate, so I guess it's OK.

Comment: If I have understood correctly the delegate in File's Owner is the class that get instantiated at the beginning of a program. So, without setting File's Owner delegate, the App Delegate will not be called. Is this correct?

Comment: It will be called as it's the delegate of the whole application.  Other views may or may not have delegate view controller classes, depending on what they are.  Only the application uses the app delegate as a delegate, generally.

Comment: So I've changed File's Owner class to "UIApplication", set the delegate (which is now in the Connections tab) to the App Delegate. Yet, the "application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" in the App Delegate method is not called. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Check your MainWindow.xib.

1. Add appDelegate object below your window (in xib).
2. Set your class property for appDelegate object to your own appdelegate class.
3. Then your window object should be connected to appdelegate object's window property.
4. Now in codebase create object of your viewController class and add subview to window.

Hope this steps will give you some idea about code.

I guess you must have already followed all these steps.