# EXC_BAD_ACCESS right after touchesBegan

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, touchesbegan

I have started a very simple project to learn iOS programming, but I get **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** after `touchesBegan`.

You can download the project from DropBox here .

I basically have a `UIView` subclass that should draw circles wherever the user is touching.

Very simple but I cannot make it work.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Turns out the problem is this line of code in `touchesBegan`:

```
    ts = [NSMutableSet setWithSet: [event touchesForView:self]];
```

That I changed into:

```
    ts = [[NSMutableSet setWithSet: [event touchesForView:self]] retain];
```

Comment: You should post a minimal code example and/or crash reports to reproduce your problem, not the entire project :/

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that, given the dimension of the projects, it would be faster to just post the project.

Comment: Faster for you -- but slower for answerers.  I think you got lucky that @debleek63 went through the trouble (deserves more upvotes).

Comment: You're right, I have edited the answer to make it more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use ARC??? :) Its good! You do not retain your `ts` set. Note, that `setWithSet:` returns you autoreleased instance. (The red circle looks promising :))

Comment: Thank you! I think this fixes it. Just a quick question: do I always have to retain an object that I get from a method that is NOT alloc/copy?

Comment: If you call alloc, call release.  If you call retain, call release.  If you call copy, call release.  All other functions PROBABLY return autoreleased objects, so don't call release.  However, I would definitely read docs of all non-Apple supplied API's because I wouldn't trust that this was followed by everyone -- it's a naming convention, not compiler checked.

Comment: Thank you very much. I disabled ARC just to learn a little bit about memory mgmt in objective-c. In the future I'll make sure to check the API doc. Thanks for your help everybody!

Answer (score 2):

BAD_ACCESS errors are generally related to referencing objects that no longer exist (i.e. they were deallocated or they were autoreleased). Check for these issues inside `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnded`:

1. Any incorrect placement of `release` calls, when an object is still going to be used. Try commenting them out and see if the error is gone.
2. Using autoreleased objects and not retaining them. Autoreleased objects are the ones created using the method names that refer directly to the class, like these: `[NSString stringWith...]` or `[NSArray arrayWith...]`, instead of using `alloc` and `init`.

For further help, please try to include some code snippets for these methods.

Comment: Answering the question you have just asked above, yes, any object not created with `alloc` and `init` should be retained.

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new here and unfortunately I cannot upvote.

Answer (score 0):

To know the reason of BAD_ACCESS use Zombie in xCode, check the link
http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/